# Laravel how to update view in shraed hosting?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have shared hosting on GoDaddy and I deployed laravel project the problem I am facing is the following:

I updated view file but it seem that laravel is serving old view.

I followed [this youtube video for deployment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6g8G3YQtQt4)

how to make laravel serve my new view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel you need to clear cache and views, Since you do not have ssh permission to run artisan commands, you need to delete them manually (i. e. via FTP).

Delete the following files

- bootstrap/cache/packages.php
- bootstrap/cache/services.php
- storage/framework/cache/data/deleteallexceptgitignore
- storage/framework/sessions/deleteallexceptgitignore
- storage/framework/views/deleteallexceptgitignore

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create route support clear cache, view , config example

```
//Clear configurations:
                Route::get('/config-clear', function() {
                    $status = Artisan::call('config:clear');
                    return '<h1>Configurations cleared</h1>';
                });

    //Clear cache:
                Route::get('/cache-clear', function() {
                    $status = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
                    return '<h1>Cache cleared</h1>';
                });

    //Clear configuration cache:
                Route::get('/config-cache', function() {
                    $status = Artisan::call('config:Cache');
                    return '<h1>Configurations cache cleared</h1>';
                });
```